# Proof of "continuity from above" and "continuity from below" from the axioms of probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

One of the consequences of the axioms of probability ($\sigma$ field and probability axiom) is the "infinite subset" and "infinite union" property, I can't figure out how it follows from them.

if $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots$ then

$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i \right) = \lim_{k \to \infty} P(A_k)  $$

If $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \cdots$ then

$$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i \right) = \lim_{k \to \infty} P(A_k)  $$

Comment: And... what is it exactly that escapes you?

Comment: I think you need to use the fact that probability is an additive function on the sets defined by the sample space.

Comment: see a detailed proof here: http://www.randomservices.org/random/prob/Measure.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The properties that you mention in your question are traditionally referred to as "continuity from above" and "continuity from below" respectively (see the math.stackexchange question [Continuity from below and above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234292/continuity-from-below-and-above) for a justification of this terminology).

As for understanding how these properties follow from $\sigma$-field axioms such as

> **Countable additivity:** if $\{E_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ are disjoint events,
>   then $$\Pr\left[\bigcup_nE_n\right]=\sum_n\Pr[E_n]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\Pr[E_i],$$

one of the best ways to get an idea of how to proceed is to look at drawings of sets.

Let's look at the example where $A_1\subset A_2\subset A_3\subset A_4\subset\cdots$
(continuity from below).
One can represent these sets graphically as (only $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are drawn):
[image: Drawing1]

Suppose that we define sets $B_1,B_2,B_3,\ldots$ as
$$B_1=A_1\\
B_2=A_2\setminus A_1\\
B_3=A_3\setminus(A_1\cup A_2)\\
\ldots\\
B_n=A_n\setminus(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{n-1})\\
\ldots,$$
and so on.
Graphically,
this would look like:
[image]

Then,
it seems intuitive enough that the union of every $A_i$ up to $n$ and the union of every $B_i$ up to $n$ are the same for every $n$,
and that the $B_i$ are disjoint (though one still needs to demonstrate this rigorously).
With this in mind,
the solution should become clear (hint: use countable additivity).

Using similar reasoning by drawings/illustrations,
you should be able to solve your second problem.

(**Note:** I did not create the illustrations in this post.)

Comment: I appreciate the graphics!

Comment: I do not understand why is it not the case that $P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right )=P\left(A_1 \right )$ because of $ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i=A_1 $. Why do we need the limit in the proof of continuity from above?

Comment: @Fazzolini any answer to question above?