# Real Analysis Folland, Problem 1.3.8 Measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measure space and $\{E_j\}_{1}^{\infty}\subset M$, then $\mu(\liminf E_j) \leq \liminf \mu(E_j)$.

Attempted proof - Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space and $\{E_j\}_{1}^{\infty}\subset M$. Notice that $\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty} E_j = \cap E_k\cap E_{k+1}\cap\ldots$ which is increasing so $\{\bigcap_{1}^{\infty}E_k\}$ is an increasing sequence of sets so $\mu(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j) \leq \mu(E_k)$. We know that $$\liminf E_j = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j$$ So $$\mu(\liminf E_j) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right)\right) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right) = \liminf\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right) \leq \liminf\mu(E_j)$$ Therefore we must have $$\mu(\liminf E_j) \leq \liminf \mu(E_j)$$

I am somewhat skeptical of this result if anyone could provide some reasoning I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: [See here, continuity of measures](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/234292/192336)

Comment: I know that proposition but I do not understand how it equals $\liminf....$

Comment: $\mu(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j) \leq \mu(E_j)$ should be $\mu(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j) \leq \mu(E_k)$. The $j$ is a running index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $F_{k}=\bigcap\limits_{j=k}^{\infty} E_{j}$, then $\{F_{k}\}$ is an increasing sequence of sets. By definition $\lim\inf E_{j}=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} F_{k}$.

By Theorem 1.8.c (Continuity from below) in Folland's book, we get
$$\mu\left(\lim\inf E_{j}\right)=\mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} F_{k}\right)=\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mu\left(F_{k}\right)=\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mu\left(\bigcap\limits_{j=k}^{\infty} E_{j}\right)$$ 
By definition 
$$\lim\inf\mu\left(E_{j}\right)=\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}\inf\{\mu\left(E_{j}\right) \mid j\geqslant k\}$$
Since $\mu\left(\bigcap\limits_{j=k}^{\infty} E_{j}\right)\leqslant \mu\left(E_{j}\right)$ for all $j \geqslant k$, we must have $\mu\left(\bigcap\limits_{j=k}^{\infty} E_{j}\right)\leqslant \inf\{\mu\left(E_{j}\right) \mid j\geqslant k\}$

Therefore, we have 
$$\mu\left(\lim\inf E_{j}\right)\leqslant\lim\inf\mu\left(E_{j}\right)$$

Comment: It makes sense to that since $\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right)\leq \mu(E_j)$ then we should have the result but I am somewhat skeptical

Comment: Which part of the argument confuse you?

Comment: Actually I think I get it now I made a edit to my proof can you see if it is correct?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right)\leqslant\mu(E_j)$ is kind of unclear to me. It seems like you view $j$ as a fixed index. I think you should use $E_k$ instead of $E_j$.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right)=\liminf\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right)\leqslant \liminf \mu(E_{k})=\liminf \mu(E_{j})$

Comment: $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right) = \liminf\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right)$ how did you get that is that a definition I am not aware of?

Comment: If the limit exists, then we will have $\liminf\mu\left(\bigcap\limits_{j=k}^{\infty}E_{j}\right)=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mu\left(\bigcap\limits_{j=k}^{\infty}E_{j}\right)$. Theorem 1.8.c (Continuity from below) provide us that limit does exist.

Comment: Ok, I got it now thanks

Comment: edited my answer I think it is correct now based on your comment