# Prove that $X$ is a.s. constant and $Y_n$ converges to a constant a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> 1. Let $X$ be a random variable with the property that $P(X\leq t)$ is either $0$ or $1$. Prove that $X$ is a.s. constant.
> 2. Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is an i.i.d. of random variables and $\{y_n\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers that tends to $+\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. The sequence $\displaystyle Y_n=\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{y_n}$ converges a.s. Prove it converges to a constant a.s.

For 1, what I need is there is a constant $C$ such that $P(X=C)=1$. Intutively it seems correct, but I have hard time proving it rigourously. Any hint/help is appreciated.

For 2. what I have is there is some function $Y$ such that $P(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} Y_n(\omega)=Y(\omega))=1$, and what I need to prove is  $Y(\omega)$ is independent of $\omega$. But stuck on that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $t\mapsto P(X\le t)$ is increasing. So there must be some $t_0$ where it jumps from $0$ to $1$, right? The function is also right-continuous...

Comment: amsmath: How do we prove it is right continuous?

Comment: Call that function $f$. We need the right-continuity for having $f(t_0) = 1$, where $t_0$ is the point where it jumps. The right-continuity follows from the continuity of measure: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234292/continuity-from-below-and-above

Comment: Ok so we are using continuity from above right?

Comment: Exactly. Now,$$\{X\neq t_0\} = \bigcup_n\{X > t_0+\frac 1 n\}\,\cup\,\bigcup_n\{X\le t_0-\frac 1 n\}.$$Show that all these sets have measure zero and use continuity of measure from below.

Comment: amsmath: Do you have any idea of 2?

Comment: It looks like this problem is setting you up to use the Kolmogorov 0-1 law.

Comment: Michael: Good point. So, can I take $\{Y(\omega)\leq t\}$ for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$ as a tail event?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n=X_1+\cdots +X_n$. If $EX_1=0$, 
$$
\dfrac{S_n}{y_n}\to 0
$$
a.s. (see Chung's A Course in Probability Theory, p.132, Corollary). Assume that 
$\mu =EX_1\neq 0$ and let $Y=\lim _n(S_n/y_n)$. By the SLLN, 
$$
\mu ^{-1}Y=\lim _n\left (\dfrac{S_n}{n}\right )^{-1}\left (\dfrac{S_n}{y_n}\right )=\lim _n\dfrac{n}{y_n}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Kolmogorov's 0-1 law. Let $Y_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} Y$ and $Z=\limsup_{n\to\infty}{Y_n}$. Then since $y_n\to\infty$, for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$, the event $\{Z\le t\}$ is a tail event. Now
$$
\mathsf{P}(Y\le t)=\mathsf{P}(Y\le t,Z=Y)+\mathsf{P}(Y\le t,Z\ne Y)=\mathsf{P}(Z\le t)
$$
and $\mathsf{P}(Z\le t)\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with lot of terms here. What does "exchangeable" means and what is Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law?