# Limit of measure of sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory

Recently in my class there was talk of a sequence of sets $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \dots $, where each set has infinite measure. Although I found an example that violated the equality (which was the point of the exercise):
$$\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mu(A_n),$$
namely,
$$ A_n = [n, \infty[, \text{ where } n \in \mathbb{N}^+,$$
I am still a bit puzzled at how I did it. I can see that the measure of the intersection of the sets is  $0$, as can be shown be contradiction (assume it weren't empty, containing a positive real number $r$; but then $r \notin [\lceil{r}\rceil, \infty[$, so it cannot be an intersection of all the sets). 
 Regarding $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu(A_n)$, I'm somewhat conflicted:

- On the one hand, $\forall  \ n \ \mu(A_n) = \infty$. Hence, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \infty = \infty$
- On the other hand, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n = \varnothing$. Hence, $\mu(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n) = 0$.

---

So am I right to conclude that in general $\mu(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n) \neq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu(A_n)$? Why?
Thanks for clarifying these issues.

Comment: You are right. Indeed, this is a basic theorem in measure theory (look up [continuity from above](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/234292/169852)), but with the additional hypothesis that $\mu(A_1) < \infty$, and your example is a typical one illustrating why that hypothesis is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right to conclude that, and you're right to conclude that because you've found a counterexample.