# (T/F) If $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $A$ is a Borel set such that $\mu(A \cap K) = 0$ for all compact sets $K$, then $\mu(A) = 0$.

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

I am trying to prove or disprove the following statement:

If $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $A$ is a Borel set such that $\mu(A \cap K) = 0$ for all compact sets $K$, then $\mu(A) = 0$.

I am looking for intuition behind the statement, since I am still trying to understand the Borel sigma-algebra.

Comment: Wikipedia indicates that some authors require that a Borel measure be locally compact. Do you require this, or have you defined a Borel measure as just one whose sigma algebra contains the Borel sigma algebra?

Comment: Our definition of a Borel measure is simply a measure on a Borel sigma-algebra.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Every $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on a Polish space is inner regular for compacta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\mu(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A\cap[-n,n])=0.
$$

Comment: Seems to be true, but what are you trying to show? How do you know that every compact set has the form $[-n,n]$ for some $n$? Isn't $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ compact, for instance?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234292/continuity-from-below-and-above

Comment: You stated that $\mu(A \cap K) = 0$ for all compact $K$. In particular, this is true for $K=[-n,n]$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note by countable additivity of measure,

$0 \leq \mu(A)= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \mu(A \cap (n,n+1]) \leq \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \mu(A \cap [n,n+1])= 0$

Hence $\mu(A)=0$.

Comment: Missing $\mu$? Also the second "$=$" should be "$\le$"...

Comment: I missed it. Thanks.