# Continuity Theorem of Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I came across this Theorem in Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and I don't understand what it is stating:

> Let ${C_n}$ be a nondecreasing sequence of events. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(C_n) = P(\lim_{n\to\infty} C_n) = P(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty C_n).$$

P is a probability function here. I understand the statement that $\lim_{n\to\infty} C_n = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ for a nondecreasing sequence of events, but that is a result of set theory. What is the significance of interchanging P and the limit in the theorem above?

Comment: Its a property of measures known as continuity from below.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234292/continuity-from-below-and-above

Comment: You want a proof of it or you want why interchanging limit and P is important?