# What is the measure of $[x, x+\frac{1}{n})$?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$

How could we interpret $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}$ measure $\{[x,x+\frac{1}{n})\}$ ?

Initially, we might be tempted to think that $x+\varepsilon \to x$ as $n \to \infty$ in which case our set becomes infinitely close to $\{x\}$.

Then, another idea is to consider the infemum of $[x,x+\varepsilon)$ which is just $x$ but that takes us back to the above statement.

Are there any ideas on how to measure this set as $n$ increases arbitrarily?

Comment: I would say the measure of $[x,x+\frac1n)$ is $\frac1n$, which approaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity from above: Let $E_n$ be a decreasing sequence of measurable sets with some set with finite measure. Then $m (E_n)$ converges to $m(E)$ where $E$ is the limit of the sequence.

Note that the sequence you have is a decreasing one, and every set has a finite measure. I think it helps.  Please take a look.

[Continuity from below and above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234292/continuity-from-below-and-above)

Comment: Whether or not they have finite measure really depends on the measure they are using

Comment: Yes. That's right. I considered Lebesgue measure here. Thanks for pointing out the issue.