# Help understanding where my proof is wrong (proving that a certain set is a Dynkin system)

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

So I was reading Measures, Integrals and Martingales (second edition), by Schilling, and upon reaching chapter 5 (the one on uniqueness of measures), I came to exercise 5.12 which states:

A Boolean algebra $\mathscr{C}$ on a set $\mathit{X}$  is a subset of $\mathscr{P(\mathit{X})}$ (the power set of $\mathit{X}$)                                                                                                      such that $\mathit{X}$ is in $\mathscr{C}$, and $\mathscr{C}$ is closed under the fomation of finite unions and intersections and complements. If $\mathscr{A}= \sigma(\mathscr{C})$ (the sigma algebra generated by the collection $\mathscr{C}$), and $\mu$ is a finite measure on the measurable space ($\mathit{X}$, $\mathscr{A}$), then prove that:

$\forall$$\mathit{A}$$\in$$\mathscr{A}$, $\forall$$\varepsilon$$\gt$$0$ $\exists$$\mathit{C}$$\in$$\mathscr{C}$ such that $\mu(\mathit{A}\bigtriangleup\mathit{C} )$ $\lt$ $\varepsilon$, where $\bigtriangleup$ is the symmetric difference of two sets, that is $\mathit{A}\bigtriangleup\mathit{C}$=$(\mathit{A}\setminus\mathit{C})$$\sqcup$$(\mathit{C}\setminus\mathit{A})$

The exercise itself has two more requests, but I managed to do them just fine. To show that this statement is true, as the author suggests, I tried to prove that the set:

$$\mathscr{D}=\{\, \mathit{A}\in\mathscr{A}\, \mid\, (\forall\varepsilon\gt0 \, \exists\mathit{C}\in\mathscr{C}\, \mid \, \mu(\mathit{A}\bigtriangleup\mathit{C})\lt\varepsilon)\, \}$$

is a Dynkin system containing $\mathscr{C}$, so that we may use the fact that by minimality, the smallest Dynkin system which contains $\mathscr{C}$ (which is also the sigma algebra generated by $\mathscr{C}$ since this set is closed under finite intersections) is contained in $\mathscr{D}$. My main concern is, upon attempting to prove that the disjoint union of countable sets from $\mathscr{D}$ is in $\mathscr{D}$ I fail to realize where my proof needs the fact that this union is actually disjoint. Moreover I think I don't even need the fact that the measure is finite. So I thought it'd be better posting my attempt at proving this on here to see if anyone can spot the error(s). That being said my proof is as follows:

Let $(\mathit{A_n})$$\subset$$\mathscr{D}$ be a countable sequence and $\varepsilon$$\gt$$0$ be arbitrary. By definition of $\mathscr{D}$, we may then find another countable sequence of sets $(\mathit{C_n})$$\subset$$\mathscr{C}$ such that $\mu(\mathit{A_n}\bigtriangleup\mathit{C_n})$$\lt$$(\frac{\varepsilon}{4})$$\frac{1}{2^n}$$\\,$$\forall$$n$$\in$$\mathbb{N}$. Write $\mathit{A}$=$\bigcup{\mathit{A_n}}$, and define $\mathit{G_n}$=$\bigcup_1^n{C_j}$. My claim is that $\lim_{n\to \infty}$$\mu(\mathit{A}\bigtriangleup\mathit{G_n})$$\leqslant$$\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. To prove this, note first that $\mathit{G_n}$$\uparrow$$\mathit{C}$$=$$\bigcup{C_j}$, which in turn implies both that ($\mathit{G_n}$$\setminus$$\mathit{A}$)$\uparrow$($\mathit{C}$$\setminus$$\mathit{A}$), and ($\mathit{A}$$\setminus$$\mathit{G_n}$)$\downarrow$($\mathit{A}$$\setminus$$\mathit{C}$).

Next note that by the definition of the symmetric difference we have: $$\mu(\mathit{A}\bigtriangleup\mathit{G_n})=\mu(\mathit{A}\setminus\mathit{G_n})+\mu(\mathit{G_n}\setminus\mathit{A})$$ And by properties of limits and measures we then have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(\mathit{A}\bigtriangleup\mathit{G_n})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(\mathit{A}\setminus\mathit{G_n})+\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(\mathit{G_n}\setminus\mathit{A})=\mu(\mathit{A}\setminus\mathit{C})+\mu(\mathit{C}\setminus\mathit{A})$$
If we now write $\mathit{A}\setminus\mathit{C}$$\,$ as $\,$$\bigcup{\mathit{A_k}}\setminus\bigcup{\mathit{C_k}}$, we note that $\mathit{A}\setminus\mathit{C}$$\,$$\subseteq$$\,$$\bigcup({\mathit{A_k}\setminus\mathit{C_k}})$. Similarly one has that $\mathit{C}\setminus\mathit{A}$$\,$$\subseteq$$\,$$\bigcup{(\mathit{C_k}\setminus\mathit{A_k})}$.   From this we know that
$$\mu(\mathit{A}\setminus\mathit{C})+\mu(\mathit{C}\setminus\mathit{A})\,\le\,\mu(\bigcup({\mathit{A_k}\setminus\mathit{C_k}})+\mu(\bigcup{(\mathit{C_k}\setminus\mathit{A_k})})$$
And by properties of measures we may write a further inequality, which is:
$$\mu(\bigcup({\mathit{A_k}\setminus\mathit{C_k}})+\mu(\bigcup{(\mathit{C_k}\setminus\mathit{A_k})})\,\le\,\sum{\mu(\mathit{A_k}\setminus\mathit{C_k})}+\sum{\mu(\mathit{C_k}\setminus\mathit{A_k})}$$
If we now recall how the sequence ($\mathit{C_n}$) was chosen, we note that both the arguments in the infinte sums are bounud to be less than or equal to $(\frac{\varepsilon}{4})$$\frac{1}{2^k}$, hence by a simple use of a geometric series we arrive at the inequality $$\mathit{l}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(\mathit{A}\bigtriangleup\mathit{G_n})\,\le \, \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
Now we use the definition of a limit to find ourselves an number $\mathit{N}\in\mathbb{N}\,$ such that if $n\gt\mathit{N}\,$ then
$$| \mu(\mathit{A}\bigtriangleup\mathit{G_n})-\mathit{l} |\,\lt \,\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
Then by properties of absolute values and the fact that our limit $\mathit{l}$ is less than or equal to $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, we easily get that $\forall n\gt\mathit{N}$
$$\mu(\mathit{A}\bigtriangleup\mathit{G_n})\, \lt \, \varepsilon$$
And since our set $\mathscr{C}$, is closed under finite unions, we managed to show that $\mathit{A}=\bigcup{A_n}$, is in $\mathscr{D}$, which in the end implies that this set is a sigma algebra.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you did not need the assumption that the $A_n$ are disjoint.  So indeed, you actually proved directly that $\mathscr{D}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (complements are easy) and so there is no need to use the Dynkin lemma.  This is how the traditional proof goes; see for instance [Approximating a $\sigma$-algebra by a generating algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228998/approximating-a-sigma-algebra-by-a-generating-algebra).  Maybe the author is just so accustomed to using the Dynkin lemma (it is a very powerful tool) that they didn't notice it is unnecessary here.

But you did use the assumption that $\mu$ is finite. When you claimed that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(\mathit{A}\bigtriangleup\mathit{G_n})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(\mathit{A}\setminus\mathit{G_n})+\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(\mathit{G_n}\setminus\mathit{A})=\mu(\mathit{A}\setminus\mathit{C})+\mu(\mathit{C}\setminus\mathit{A})$$
you had $A \setminus G_n \, \downarrow\, A \setminus C$ and wanted to conclude that $\lim \mu(A \setminus G_n) = \mu(A \setminus C)$, the so-called ["continuity from above" property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234292/continuity-from-below-and-above).  But that is only valid under the assumption that $\mu(A \setminus G_n)  <\infty$ for all (sufficiently large) $n$.

Other than that, I think your proof is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did not recall that I needed that condition to use the continuity of the measure, I should look it up

Comment: @Evan: The continuity from below is true without any finiteness conditions.  It's only continuity from above that needs the extra hypothesis.  It's easy to forget about this when doing probability theory, where we work almost exclusively with finite measures!